# How to show an AxesSubplot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an object fig2 that is a class mathplotlib.axes.axessubplot, but when I try to execute fig2.show(), python says axessubplot object has no attribute show. How can I show AxesSubplot?[image]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You should call `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`, which is a method that displays all the figures.

If you have imported as `plt`, then:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create fig1 (of type plt.figure)
# create fig2

plt.show()  # will display fig1 and fig2 in different windows
```

Answer (score 38):

Alternatively, you could call the figure attribute of your fig2:

```
fig2.figure
```

Comment: Very useful with the objects a Seaborn lineplot presently returns. You can have the plot display again in another Jupyter cell without running all the code again.

Comment: Also, this was the only line of code that worked on Databricks when I was trying to display dicom files with matplotlib. Thanks!

Comment: I've really struggled to discern when/how to show, customize, and pass-around `pyplot` objects and this simple insight helped me tremendously. Go `figure`...

Answer (score -1):

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` - This statement will remove the error.

`without thr first line, plt.show()` would throw an attribute error.

`plt.show()`